# How to Prevent CSRF in Ruby on Rails

Tags: attack-prevention

How can I prevent CSRF in Ruby on Rails programming ? Is it possible to avoid overload on the application loading on net ?

Answer (score 2):

Ruby on Rails basically makes use of a **Security Token**, which if also a [recommended way of preventing CSFR attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#General_Recommendation:_Synchronizer_Token_Pattern), to prevent CSRF attacks.

You must include a security token using: `protect_from_forgery` in your requests and MUST verify it on the server. This will automatically include a security token in all forms and Ajax requests generated by Rails. If the security token doesn't match what was expected, the session will be reset.

Source: [Ruby on Rails Security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf).